# How can I replace text variables on a live preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, preview

I have a definition list with associated variables and their values.  (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAzZr/) too)

```
<dl id="myVars">
    <dt class="var-name">%name%</dt>
    <dd class="var-name">Joe Sample</dd>
    <dt class="var-phone">%phone%</dt>
    <dd class="var-phone">555-1212</dd>
</dl>
```

I also have a textarea that one can use any of the above variables within their text.  For example:

```
<textarea>Hello %name%, is this still the right phone number: %phone%?</textarea>
```

Finally there's a preview div where one can see the interpreted text after the variables are replaced.  Like so:

```
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Can you help me come up with an efficient way to use jQuery to show live previews at the same time it replaces variables with their values?

Here's a handy fiddle if you're up for helping: http://jsfiddle.net/XAzZr/

Comment: I'd like it to not replace anything until a variable is fully completed, so the preview might say "Hello %name" until you enter the closing `%` sign.  Then the preview would read "Hello Joe Sample".  Of course the textarea would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NFtVc/

```
var subst = {}, // store substitutions in an object to eliminate DOM lookups
    substRegex = /(.*)%(\S*)%(.*)$/i;

function defineSubst(){
    $("#myVars dd").each(function(){
        var cls = this.className.split(' '),
            l = cls.length;
        while (l--){
            if (cls[l].indexOf('var-') == 0)   
               subst[cls[l].replace(/var-/, "")] = this.innerHTML;   
        } 
    });
}

function getSubst(key){
    if (typeof subst[key] == "undefined")
        return "[INVALID CODE]";
    else
        return subst[key];        
}

function updatePreview(){
     var txt = $('textarea').val().split(' '),
        newTxts = [],
        regex = /(.*)%(\S*)%(.*)$/i;

    $.each(txt, function(){
        var m = substRegex.exec(this);
        if (m)
            newTxts.push(m[1] + getSubst(m[2]) + m[3]);
        else
            newTxts.push(this);
    });

    $("#preview").text(newTxts.join(' '));  
}

$('document').ready(defineSubst);
$('textarea').keyup(updatePreview);
```

Comment: Beautiful. This is really close, but it breaks in a couple of key places. For example: `%name%'s phone number is (%phone%)`. Can you point me in the right direction to get me across the finish line?

Comment: Updated. The first split on space might be overkill, but it does allow for a string like "Hi %name%, you are 20% of goal A and 30% of goal B" without getting crazy on the regex.

Comment: Impressive test case, executed flawlessly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    var message = this.value.replace(/%(.*?)\S+/g, function(val) {
        var elem = $('dt').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == val;
        });
        return elem.length ? elem.next('dd').text() : '';
    });

    $('#preview').text(message);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XAzZr/3/)

Comment: Beautiful. Can you help me make this work even if the string isn't surrounded by spaces?  For example: `%name%'s phone number is (%phone%)`

Comment: Yes, this was better, but still failed with something like: `Hi %name%, you are 20% of goal A and 30% of goal B` . But Malk got it done without too much hassle. Thanks for your help.